# Which PHP version lets you get away without copying INI file to each directory?

Tags: php, ini

I've been having problems with PHP session variables since starting work on a new website for a company I work for. I phoned the hosting provider (1and1) and I was told it was because I needed to copy an INI file into each directory I make.

I recall facing this problem before, and somehow finding a list of PHP versions that you don't need to copy the INI file to each sub-directory, to use sessions with. I just can't seem to find such information on Google (despite searching for a few hours). Does anyone know what PHP version I need to downgrade to, in order to use session variables again, without having to manually copy the INI file into each of the X thousand directories I have?

Comment: umm.. it sounds like the real answer here is to change hosts. That is not something you should have to do. Not even on shared hosting

Comment: It doesn't make sense that hosting provider would answer with "please copy a PHP.ini file to each directory you make if you want to use session variables". This smells to be an XY problem and I suggest that you ask about the problem you have with sessions rather than asking what PHP version you need so you can copy the INI file to directories.

Comment: Quite a few shared hosts allow per-account ini settings, but you only need to set up the file once in your user directory. I've never heard of a configuration where it is required for _every_ directory. This is extremely unusual - I would speak to someone else in support to double-check, and if it is really the case, change hosts as Crayon suggests.

Comment: This is a ridiculous claim from your hosting provider. Recheck if this is really needed, if they confirm it - change host.

Answer (score 1):

I called them back and somebody else answered, who claimed to have changed something in the accounts PHP setup, after I described my problem to him. It now works fine. I guess the person I spoke to previously just didn't have the expertise to help.

Happy days :)